# WARNING ITMS-90176 - Unrecognized locale base.lproj

Tags: ios, xcode

Since I updated to XCode 10, I get the following warning when uploading my app to the App Store:

> Unrecognized Locale - The locale names used in localization
>   directories at ('Payload/MyApp.app/base.lproj') are invalid. iTunes
>   supports BCP47 but not the UN M.49 specification. Refer to the
>   Language and Locale Designations guide for more information on naming
>   your language-specific directories.

Any idea how to solve this?

If not, is there a possibility to find out if this warning still occurs without doing a complete upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like only `.storyboard` and `.xib` files should be placed in base internationalization directories.

I moved all my `.strings` files from `base.lproj` to `en.lproj` directories, now the warning is gone.