# Warning when loading app to store "Unrecognized Locale"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After loading the application, a warning is issued
[image]

I found only one example of a similar solution, but I can’t figure out how to apply it in my case. Localizable.strings (Spanish ... I use it for all available countries. But the warning, as can be seen from the screen, shows only two countries. I found only one example of a similar situation [WARNING ITMS-90176 - Unrecognized locale base.lproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739742/warning-itms-90176-unrecognized-locale-base-lproj)
But I can’t figure out how to apply this to my situation and what kind of problem is this?

Comment: Maybe because EA and IC are not official country codes?